# MongoDB filter query results by $lookup array

Tags: php, mongodb

MongoDB 3.4
I have a **project** and **project_permission** collections. The project_permission collection contains permissions to the projects for some users. A single user can have multiple different permissions to the project.

```
        [
            '$lookup' => [
                'from' => ProjectPermission::collectionName(),
                'localField' => '_id',
                'foreignField' => 'project_id',
                'as' => 'project_permissions'
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$project' => [
                // ... irrelevant fields here
                'permissions' => '$project_permissions'
            ]
        ],
```

this is how the project query results looks like without filtering:

```
  // other project results
      // ... other fields
      'permissions' => [
          0 => [
              '_id' => '5d2873aafa873b2b7c000fad'
              'project_id' => '56a9e5c5d18cacc72a485839'
              'user_id' => '562f6bfc05dfe9570fb6e427'
              'permission' => 'read'
              'created_at' => 1562932138
              'updated_at' => 1562932139
          ]
          1 => [
              '_id' => '5d2879fdfa873b2b7c000fbd'
              'project_id' => '56a9e5c5d18cacc72a485839'
              'user_id' => '562f6bfc05dfe9570fb6e427'
              'permission' => 'write'
              'created_at' => 1562932139
              'updated_at' => 1562932140
          ]
          2 => [
              '_id' => '5db960b5fa873b1604005e8e'
              'project_id' => '56a9e5c5d18cacc72a485839'
              'user_id' => '582b30dd1e634e6362e1b504'
              'permission' => 'write'
              'created_at' => 1572430005
              'updated_at' => 1572430005
          ]
      ]
```

What I would like to achieve is to return with only those projects where the client - who requested the query - has a specific permission to the project, for example write.

The way I tried it:

```
pipeline: [
    0 => [
        '$match' => [
            // not related to the problem
        ]
    ]
    1 => [
        '$match' => [
            '$and' => [
                0 => [
                    'shared_permissions' => [
                        '$eq' => true
                    ]
                ]
                1 => [
                    '$or' => [
                        0 => [
                            'project_permissions' => [
                                '$exists' => true
                                '$ne' => []
                            ]
                        ]
                        1 => [
                            'owner_id' => [
                                '$ne' => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId#1
                                (
                                    [oid] => '582b30dd1e634e6362e1b504'
                                )
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    2 => [
        '$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'project_permission'
            'localField' => '_id'
            'foreignField' => 'project_id'
            'as' => 'project_permissions'
        ]
    ]
    3 => [
        '$project' => [
            // more not important fields here
            'shared_permissions' => 1
            'permissions' => [
                '$map' => [
                    'input' => [
                        '$filter' => [
                            'input' => '$project_permissions'
                            'as' => 'project_permission'
                            'cond' => [
                                '$and' => [
                                    0 => [
                                        '$eq' => ['$$project_permission.user_id', MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId#1
                                (
                                    [oid] => '582b30dd1e634e6362e1b504'
                                )
                                    ]
                                    1 => [
                                        '$eq' => ['$$project_permission.permission', 'write']
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    'as' => 'project_permission'
                    'in' => [
                        'user_id' => '$$project_permission.user_id'
                        'permission' => '$$project_permission.permission'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

For this I almost get the correct response:

```
[
  0 => [
      '_id' => '56a9e5c5d18cacc72a485839'
      'short_id' => 3
      'title' => 'Modified title'
      'owner_id' => '562f692a05dfe9560fb6e428'
      'updated_at' => 1572435428
      'owner_name' => 'Borat Sagdiyev'
      'shared_permissions' => true
      'permissions' => [
          0 => [
              'user_id' => '582b30dd1e634e6362e1b504'
              'permission' => 'write'
          ]
      ]
  ]
  1 => []
```

]

The problem with this is that empty array, where the result was filtered out - and it wouldn't be a problem if the empty array wouldn't be in the result, because if I use the pagination, then it says two results, instead of one. And we know that in the worst case we would get back an array of empty arrays only.
So what I would like to achieve is this last example results without empty arrays in a way where the pagination will be fine with it too.

ps.: unwind is not an option, because of some structural conventions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To perform an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the “joined” collection, the $lookup stage has the following syntax:

```
{
$lookup:
 {
   from: <collection to join>,
   localField: <field from the input documents>,
   foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
   as: <output array field>
 }
 }
```

Comment: Uhm.. so the problem is not with the $lookup. What I would like to achieve is to filter the project results by checking if the user has permission or not. In this case it's okay that there are multiple permissions to a single project, because admins and project owners will need to see all of the permissions. But the user, who just have permissions to different projects should be able to see the project which belongs to them.